# indexOf returns -1, why?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

I am trying to convert some XML into JSON with the module `xml2js`, I am just starting

```
    request.execute('[someSP].[spSomeSP]', function(err, dataset) {
      _.forEach(dataset, function(items) {
        _.forEach(items, function(item) {
          console.log('>>>>', item);
        });
      });
```

where `console.log('>>>>', item);` returns:

```
{ BET: 57635034,
  CUSTOMER: 181645,
  SPORT: 'NFL',
  XX_FILL_OPEN: '<element>\r\n\t<element_type>wager_action_button</element_type>\t\r\n\t<element_name>Fill Open</element_name>\r\n\t<element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call>\r\n\t<element_content></element_content>\r\n</element>',
  XX_VIEW: '<element>\r\n\t<element_type>betslip_selection_checkbox</element_type>\t\r\n\t<element_name></element_name>\r\n\t<element_call>addRemoveSelectionFromSlip_checkbox(1738756,0,1,1)</element_call>\r\n\t<element_content>0</element_content>\r\n</element>',
  XX_CANCEL: null }
```

as you can see above, there are some props starting with `XX`, every single prop starting with `XX` comes with an `XML` attribute, all I need is to convert every XML attribute into JSON, but when I do `item.indexOf('XX')` all I am getting is `-1`

so, what should I do in order to take every prop starting with `XX` in order to convert it to JSON ?

Comment: You should be getting an error on `item.indexOf` (ie `indexOf is not a function`). Regular objects do not have an `indexOf` method, arrays and like types do

Comment: Or is the output you are showing an entire string?

Comment: @PatrickEvans all I am receiving is the object you can see above. Everything starting with XX should be a JSON not an XML.

Answer (score 1):

`item` is an object. You'd could convert this to JSON and then check for `XX`:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(item);
console.log(json.indexOf('XX')); // 49
```

Or, a better approach, you could iterate through each property of the object:

```
for(var key in item) {
    if(key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(item[key]);
    }
    // Or you can also check the value here...
    // item[key].indexOf('XX')
}
```

Comment: And so it will match record with SPORT: 'XX-NFL' too, right?

Comment: maybe `=== 0`, since OP mentions _"starting with"_, otherwise it will match things like `nflXX`, `abc-XX-123`

Comment: I am trying to translate the for loop into lodash forEach but I am getting an error, possibly I'm not doing it the proper way.

Comment: and also, this: `console.log(item[key].indexOf('XX'));` throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: Actualy `item` is an object, you can't use `indexOf` or `forEach`, you need an Array for its.

Comment: The `for(var key in item) {}` loop here is *critical*...that's what loops through each property of the object. From there, you can access the values with `item[key]`. Your `item.XX_CANCEL` property is equal to `null`, so you won't be able to call `.indexOf()` on it without an error (or checking for a non-`null` value first).